# Visual Studio C# USB 4 Relay board controller

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, usb

What I want to do is to create a simple Windows form app to control a Relay board to power on and off some lights. Nothing serious it is a personal project. This the link to the relay board I have : http://www.canakit.com/catalog/product/view/id/627/s/4-port-usb-relay-controller/ .

Now my question is how can I send commands to the relay and receive some from it via USB. The relay board comes with a driver. The boards support the commands below. So how do I send 
them to the board via my windows form.

From the user manual: It is compatible with both Windows and Apple OS X, as well as various Linux flavors and appears as a USB CDC (Communications Device Class) device which creates a Virtual Serial (COM) port allowing easy communication with the board through any programming language that supports serial communications (VB, VB.NET, C#, C, C++, Perl, Java, etc). A complete set of easy to use commands are available for complete control of all relays, I/O channels and sensors.

Supported Commands:

```
RELx.ON
RELx.OFF
RELx.TOGGLE
RELx.GET

RELS.ON
RELS.OFF
RELS.GET

CHx.ON
CHx.OFF
CHx.TOGGLE
CHx.GET
CHx.SETMODE
CHx.GETANALOG
CHx.GETTEMP

CHS.ON
CHS.OFF
CHS.GET
CHS.SETTEMPRES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin the device once you have installed the driver. Open device manager where you should now see a COM port as given by board manufacturer. You could have the COM port, baud rate, parity etc. provided in the documentation. Now you can create a c# console application with following code, I have made a sample to issue a RELx.ON followed by a RELx.OFF after a 3 second gap:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace RelayConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        public static SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM5", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
/* Replace COM5 with your COM port, 9600 with baud rate of your board, parity and bits as well as per your device documentation */

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerialProgram();
        }

        static void SerialProgram()
        {
            try
            {
                port.Open();
                port.Write("RELx.ON"); /* You can pass any command as per your documentation in port.Write */
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                port.Write("RELx.OFF");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if(ex is System.IO.IOException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Port Exception: " + ex.ToString());
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("General Exception: " + ex.ToString());
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the instruction manual, the drivers give you serial port access (but no direct USB api), so you'll have to open a serial port to the relay board.

First off (if you havn't already), follow the instructions under **Communicating with the Controller** in the manual and use something like HyperTerminal to make sure you can 'talk' to the board.

Then have a look at these examples for simple serial comms from C#:

http://csharp.simpleserial.com/

http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/03/23/SerialPort-_2800_RS_2D00_232-Serial-COM-Port_2900_-in-C_2300_-.NET.aspx

Comment: I used Putty to communicate with it. It does work. What I was missing is the System.IO.Ports, in order to communicate with a port. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx).

If you already saw the documentation of that class and are having trouble using it, please elaborate on what problems you are having.